# pattern extraction matching pattern a OR pattern b (sed/awk)

Tags: awk, sed

How do I extract the word after the first `-n` whether or not there is a blank space after?

In the example below it would return `test-name` on both cases. This awk code is working properly only on the first example.

```
$ echo "a -n test-name -bc d-e -fe -ntest" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="-n  *"}{sub(/ .*/,"",$2);print $2}'                                                                              SIGINT 
test-name

$ echo "a -bc d-e -fe -ntest-name -ntest" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="-n  *"}{sub(/ .*/,"",$2);print $2}'
```

Further examples and what would be expected as a result.

```
$ echo "-ntest-name -ntest" | ...
test-name

$ echo " -n test-name -n test-n" | ...
test-name

$ echo "-na test-name -n test-n" | ...
test-n

$ echo "- n-name -nn test" | ...
n

$ echo "-a -e -i -o" | ...

$ echo "-an -en --n foo" | ...

$ echo "-nbar" | ...
bar
```

**sed** would also be a option.

Could this be done with a one-liner? Thank you.

Comment: What should the output be given input like `echo "a -x foo-name -n test-name -bc d-e -fe -ntest"`? Note the `-n` in `-x foo-name`.

Comment: @EdMorton: it should also return `test-name` . The match begins with "-n..." or "-n ..." and matches till the next whitespace.

Comment: No, the match doesn't begin with `-n` or the expected output would be `ame` given input with `-x foo-name` at the front.

Comment: @EdMorton: the match begins with " -n" (whitespace in front). The awk code that I posted would also return `test-name` using your input. It would also work properly in that case.

Comment: What should the output be if the input was `echo "-n test-name -bc"` without whitespace before the `-n`? For that previous case, the awk code you provided would only "work" for the previous case I mentioned because it doesn't work for the case you're asking for help with.

Comment: `echo "-n test-name -bc"` as input would also return `test-name` using the awk code I posted. It'd work properly too. The tricky part is the second case, the match `a` OR match b (-ntest-name), `-n` without whitespace after.

Comment: Again, it'd "work" with your existing code because your existing code doesn't work for other cases.  I'm just trying to help you identify and tell us your full set of requirements before you get a bunch of answers that do what you asked for so far but then fail for other cases that you haven't told us about so far.

Comment: `sed '/\(^\| \)-n */!d; s//\n/; s/^.*\n//; s/ .*//'`

Comment: Given that `-n could be considered as a classic bash flag`, what should the output be given input like `echo "foo -xn test-name bar"` (which would be parsed by bash the same way as `echo "foo -x -n test-name bar"`)?

Comment: @EdMorton you mean like: `echo "x -y -- nextIsNotAnOpt -n foo` ?

Comment: @jhnc  that's not what I meant but it is another possible input to be considered.

Comment: So we can help you, please [edit] your question to explain the logic behind those desired results, e.g. why would the output of `echo "-na test-name -n test-n"` by `test-n` instead of `a`? Also respond to the existing questions you have in comments above. You had previously said we should assume that `-n` should behave like a normal bash flag - a bash flag would not behave as shown in your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `awk` approach:

```
$ echo "a -n test-name -bc d-e -fe -ntest" | awk '{line=substr($0,$0~/^-n/ ? 3 : index($0," -n")+3); split(line,a); print a[1]}' 
test-name

$ echo "a -bc d-e -fe -ntest-name -ntest"  | awk '{line=substr($0,$0~/^-n/ ? 3 : index($0," -n")+3); split(line,a); print a[1]}'
test-name

$ echo "-ntest-name a -bc d-e -fe -ntest"  | awk '{line=substr($0,$0~/^-n/ ? 3 : index($0," -n")+3); split(line,a); print a[1]}'
test-name
```

**NOTES:**

- could be further modified if there's an additional delimiter *after* the value that we need to filter for, eg, `echo "-ntest-name|new_command"` or `echo "a b -n test-name; next_command"`; would need to know the potential set of additional delimiters
- assumes the input has a valid `-n` to process otherwise this will print everything from the 3rd input character up to the 1st space (eg, `echo "test-name"` => `st-name`; this could be addressed with additional code

Comment: @EdMorton: I added in the original post that `-n` behaviours is pretty much the same as a normal bash flag.

Comment: @EdMorton Your answer works on all cases I specified. Thank you.

Comment: @jmax A script that can process finding the arg for `-n` as a "normal bash flag" would find `test-name` from input like `"foo -xn test-name bar"`.

Comment: @EdMorton : I added more examples, as it got downvoted because the question was unclear. As more examples were provided, your awk solution wouldn't return what is expected.

Comment: @jmax I didn't post a solution, I'm waiting for you to provide all relevant examples and respond to the questions from myself and others under your question. This answer you're commenting on was provided my markp-fuso.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU getopt and sed):

```
getopt -auo :n: -- -n test-name -bc d-e -fe -ntest | 
sed -E 's/^ -n (\S+).*/\1/p;d'
```

Or if you prefer:

```
getopt -auo :n: -- -n test-name -bc d-e -fe -ntest |
awk '/^ -n /{print $2}'
```

Returns the first `-n` argument.

N.B. The `-u` option to getopt returns the argument unquoted.

Comment: I get this error: `getopt: invalid option -- 'b'`

Comment: @jmox Oops! forgot to end the options. See edit.

Comment: getopt was actually a good idea, the issue is that it brings some other complexity that I wanted to avoid, like the following case:
`getopt -uo :n: -- -footestn test-name -bc d-e -fe -ntest | sed -E 's/^ -n (\S+).*/\1/p;d'`
This will return `test-name` instead of `test`

Comment: @jmox you might add the `-a` option i.e. `-auo` which allows alternative long options to begin with a single `-` which for your examples still returns `test-name` and for the above comment `test`?

Comment: it did the trick using `-auo`. Could you update your answer? I'll mark it as a solution. Thanks.